# Weakness for Singleton at Java Memory Model with synchronized Blocks

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton, data-synchronization, java-memory-model

I am reading Nir Shavit's The Art of Multiprocessor Computing. It explains Java Memory Model and gives an example at page 62:

```
public static Singleton getInstance() {
  if (instance == null) {
    synchronized(Singleton.class) {
      if (instance == null)
      instance = new Singleton();
    }
  }
  return instance;
}
```

and says that:

> This pattern, once common, is incorrect. At Line 5, the constructor
>   call appears to take place before the instance field is assigned, but
>   the Java memory model allows these steps to occur out of order,
>   effectively making a partially initialized Singleton object visible to
>   other programs.

So, does it mean that such kind of synchronization may not guarantee what we want from Singleton?

Answer (score 1):

> So, does it mean that such kind of synchronization may not guarantee
>   what we want from Singleton?

It depends what you want from the singleton. If you want only one instance, the solution in your snippet will achieve that. If you want only one instance **and you want that instance to be perfectly initialized when you access it** (is that too much to ask?), then, no, you won't achieve that with the snippet.

Another thread calling `getInstance` and reading the value of the `instance` field

```
if (instance == null) {
```

might see an assigned value referencing an object which has yet to be initialized by the controller. Since that value is not `null`, the method returns it and the uninitialized object leaks.

This is fixed by marking the field as `volatile`.

Comment: However book also says that: `Although reading and writing a volatile field has the same effect on mem-
ory consistency as acquiring and releasing a lock, multiple reads–writes are not
atomic. For example, if x is a volatile variable, the expression x++ will not nec-
essarily increment x if concurrent threads can modify x. Some form of mutual
exclusion is needed as well. One common usage pattern for volatile variables
occurs when a field is read by multiple threads, but only written by one.`

Comment: @RealSkeptic , as Sotirios Delimanolis edited his answerI want a stable object (this may not break singleton contract as a term). Sotirios Delimanolis , are you sure this can be fixed with volatile due to my first comment at your answer.

Comment: @kamaci Yes, so `x++` is two operations, it's a read of `x` and a write of `x`. That means `x++` as an operation is not atomic. If some other thread writes to `x` before the `++` can be written, you'll lose that write. In this case, we assume the only thread that can write to `instance` is the one that entered the `synchronized` block.

Comment: So, you say that even a variable is volatile we need to synchronize it for multiple writes?

Comment: @kamaci The book is warning about the `++` case because `++` is not atomic. `volatile` reads are atomic and `volatile` writes are atomic. In your case, you want to atomically check if `instance` is `null` and initialize it if it is. That's what the body of the `synchronized` block is doing. However, to make the whole operation more efficient and not lock if not required, you check for `null` outside of the `synchronized`.

Comment: @kamaci That outside check for `null`, if not `volatile` (or another memory barrier), is not guaranteed to see a fully initialized value of the `Singleton`.